# zend Framework. Calling a different javascript file specified by action/controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I want to split a unique javascript file to get a file by action.
On my controllers I use jQuery()->addJavascriptFile() to call js files :

```
class DemandesController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{ 
  public function init()
  {
    $this->view->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile('public/js/' . $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() . '/' . $this->getRequest()->getActionName() . '.js');
  }
}
```

In my public/js folder I got a folder by controller and a js file by action...
It works well only with the indexAction, for all of the others the name of the controller is inserted into the URI :
With indexAction : http://192.168.78.208/demande_absence/public/js/demandes/index.js
With any other    : http://192.168.78.208/demande_absence/**demandes**/public/js/demandes/nouvelle.js

What I've done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 $this->view->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile('/public/js/' . $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() . '/' . $this->getRequest()->getActionName() . '.js');
```

And i think you also have to use something like the baseurl view helper to build a correct url.

Comment: baseUrl is a view helper. How can i use this in controller ?

Comment: @SiCK `$this->view->baseUrl...`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's not an absolute path. Try this:

```
$this->view->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile('/public/js/' . $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() . '/' . $this->getRequest()->getActionName() . '.js');
```

Comment: I prefer use the view->baseUrl() because the paths of dev and prod servs are differents